# Problem with converting image from depth to grayscale

Tags: ros, kinect, opencv, image-transport, depth

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am trying to convert depth image from (/camera/depth/image) to grayscale image (/camera/rgb/image_mono). This is my code.

```
#include "ros/ros.h"
#include "sensor_msgs/Image.h"
#include <std_msgs/UInt8.h>

using namespace std;
using namespace ros;

class ImageConverter
{
        NodeHandle gdd;
        Subscriber depth_sub;
        Publisher gray_pub;

        public:
        void imageCb(const sensor_msgs::Image::ConstPtr& );
        
        ImageConverter()
        {

                depth_sub = gdd.subscribe("/camera/depth/image", 1, &ImageConverter::imageCb, this);
                gray_pub = gdd.advertise<sensor_msgs::Image>("depthTOgreyscale_image", 1);                
        }
        

};

void ImageConverter::imageCb(const sensor_msgs::ImageConstPtr& depth_image)
  {

        sensor_msgs::Image gray_image;       
        gray_image.header.seq = depth_image->header.seq;
        gray_image.header.stamp = depth_image->header.stamp;
        gray_image.header.frame_id = "/camera_rgb_optical_frame";
        gray_image.height = 480;
        gray_image.width = 640;
        gray_image.encoding = "mono8";
        gray_image.is_bigendian = 0;
        gray_image.step = 640;
        
        float max_depth = 0;
        for(int i=0; i<depth_image->height; i++)
        {
                for(int j=0; j<depth_image->width; j++)
                {
                        
                        float distance = depth_image->data[i*depth_image->width+j];
                        if (distance == distance) { 
                            max_depth = max(distance, max_depth);
                        }
    
                }

        }
        ROS_INFO("%f", max_depth);
       //ACTUAL CONVERSION             
       for(int i=0; i<depth_image->height; i++)
        {
                for(int j=0; j<depth_image->width; j++)
                {
                       gray_image.data[i*depth_image->width+j] = (unsigned int)(depth_image->data[i*depth_image->width+j]/max_depth*255);    
                }

        }

        gray_pub.publish(depth_image);

}
        
        
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
        init(argc, argv, "get_depth_data");
        ImageConverter ic;               
        spin();    
        return 0;
}
```

I am able to read the depth data and convert it to UInt8C1 format but for some reason I am getting seg fault when I try to write data on my grayscale topic.

Is there a mistake I am doing I am not seeing or is there some way around it ?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/97431/problem-with-converting-image-from-depth-to-grayscale/) by [prasanna.kumar](https://answers.ros.org/users/2416/prasanna.kumar/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1363 on 2013-11-03

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Try initializing depth_image.data with an properly sized array. Also you should check if the size of the incoming image and the output match. (Or set width, height and step accordingly to the input)

---

Originally posted by [Ben_S](https://answers.ros.org/users/1072/ben_s/) with karma: 2510 on 2013-11-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0